# CUDA context was created on a GPU that is not currently debuggable

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, gpu, nsight, cuda-context

When I start Cuda debugging, Nsight returns this error:

> A CUDA context was created on a GPU that is not currently debuggable.
>   Breakpoints will be disabled.
>
> Adapter: GeForce GT 720M

I have Visual Studio 2017 and NVIDIA Nsight 5.4. Any solutions?
I read that my card is no supported by Nsight version >= 5.2.

Install older Nsight version didn't help because it doesn't support VS 2017...

Comment: This is similar to other question but is no solution

Comment: The whole point is that there is no solution. Which is discussed in the linked duplicate amswer